# What pair of words can be combined with “worth every penny” as an idiom?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context

When I was listening to AP Radio News of Eagle 810 (Far East Network), the only English language public radio broadcasting service available in Japan, together with members of a local English Speaking Society, who wish to improve English hearing proficiency, there was the following line reporting 85th Anniversary of Coney Island’s Cyclone roller coaster:

“In honor of 85th Anniversary, ride is just a quarter for the first 85 minutes, the coaster was open. Michel Hamline says it is worth every penny and ...," followed by the word that sounds something like “men some” phonetically.

We couldn’t hear out the ending words sounding like “men some.” though we tried by replaying the tape a dozen times.

I could have passed by this part, but was haunted with the question. So I'm venturing to ask:

Is there a set of words that can be combined with “worth every penny” as an idiom?

I thought “worth every penny” is a self-completing idiom sui generi, and wondered why it should be followed by anything.

Can you guess what the part that sounded like “men some” would be?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

...*and then some*, I would hazard a guess, which is an intensifier for the previous phrase.

*Worth every penny* means *great value*.
*Worth every penny, and then some* is *really really great value.*

Comment: We both got there at the same time.

Comment: suggested edit: set `and` as italic (`*and then some*`)

Comment: @Brian Hooper. I reheard the tape with ‘and then some’ in mind. Strangely, this time it sounded exactly like ‘then some.’ It’s interesting that almost 20 members of our ESS were unable to hear out the word at the listening session. I think it’s primarily because nobody had the stock of the idiom, ‘and then some’ (though I could find it on dictionaries after posting this question). For non-native foreign language learners who toil even at reading, hearing is difficult and then some.

Comment: @horatio, righto.

Comment: *Really really.* Missed a comma?

Answer (score 27):

It could have been *and then some*, meaning 'even more'.

Answer (score 10):

It is very hard to answer a question like this, but my guess is "... worth every penny and then some", meaning 'worth every penny and more'.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be "Worth every penny and mention"; meaning something like "worth the money and worth mentioning".

It would not be very good English though, but still fair enough to be broadcasted I assume.